# Show div when class appears on screen

Tags: jquery, css

So far I had this function which works:

```
var offsetTop = $(".card").offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(scrollTop > offsetTop){
    $(".popupcorner").fadeIn(200);
  }
});
```

I need small change.
I want `.popupcorner` to appear once `.card` is visible on screen, in bottom.

Comment: When does `.popupcorner` appear currently? It seems like you're checking whether it is visible or not already. Are you asking how to check if `.card` is visible or how to change the position of `.popupcorner`?

Comment: I am asking that how to check is .card visible on screen, in another words, once screen has even one pixel of .card, .popupcorner should pop in.

Comment: .popupcorner currently appears when I fully scroll over .card.

Comment: @Ale Plo, I don't quite understand, may you write an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is to reveal the `.popupcorner` as soon as the card is visible from the bottom. If so, then the function `getBoundingClientRect` can come in handy. It gives you the position of an element relative to the viewport.

```
var rect = $(".card")[0].getBoundingClientRect()
// if element's top is "above" the bottom of the screen
if(rect.top < window.innerHeight){
    $(".popupcorner").fadeIn(200);
}
```

Comment: It only works, if I refresh page, staying on .card currently.

Comment: @mariobalser this code has to be inside your `scroll` event handler

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this if your browser support allows for it, since it's more performant than a `scroll` listener. When used with the [default options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Intersection_observer_options) it'll fire as soon as 1px of the target element comes into view.

```
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
  // Callback will fire once when we set it up, so we check if the element 
  // is actually in the viewport.
  if (entries.filter((entry) => entry.isIntersecting).length != 0) {
    $('.popupcorner').fadeIn();
    // Once the element is in view, work is done. Dispose of the observer.
    observer.disconnect();
  }
});

observer.observe($('.card')[0]);
```